# Perl + Unicode: "Wide Strings" error

Tags: perl, unicode, utf

I am running Active Perl 5.14 on Windows 7. 
I am trying to write a program that will read-in a conversion table, then work on a file and replace certain patterns by other patterns - all of the above in Unicode (UTF-8). Here is the beginning of the program:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
# Load a conversion table from CONVTABLE to %ConvTable.
# Then find matches in a file and convert them.
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;
use 5.014;
use utf8;
use autodie; 
use warnings    qw< FATAL  utf8     >;
use open        qw< :std  :utf8     >;
use charnames   qw< :full >;
use feature     qw< unicode_strings >;

my ($i,$j,$InputFile, $OutputFile,$word,$from,$to,$linetoprint);
my (@line, @lineout); 
my %ConvTable;    # Conversion hash
print 'Conversion table: opening file: E:\My Documents\Perl\Conversion table.txt'."\n";
my $sta= open (CONVTABLE, "<:encoding(utf8)", 'E:\My Documents\Perl\Conversion table.txt');
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';    # output should be in UTF-8
# Load conversion hash
while (<CONVTABLE>) {
    chomp;
    print "$_\n"; # etc ...
# etc ...
```

It turns out that at this point, it says:

```
wide character in print at (eval 155)E:/Active Perl/lib/Perl5DB.pl:640]line 2, <CONVTABLE> line 1, etc...
```

Why is that? I think I've gone through and implemented all the necessary prescriptions for correct handling of Unicode strings, decoding and encoding into UTF-8?
And how to fix it?

TIA

Helen

Comment: Your code is fine. What happens if you run it outside of the debugger?

Comment: By the way, the `binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';` is redundant with the same being done by `use open qw< :std :utf8 >;`.

Comment: By the way, the `use feature qw< unicode_strings >;` (which has no effect on that code) is redundant with the same being done by `use 5.014;`.

Comment: [crossposted on PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=954045)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Perl debugger has its own output handle that is distinct from `STDOUT` (although it may ultimately go to the same place as `STDOUT`). You'll also want to do something like this near the beginning of your script:

```
binmode $DB::OUT, ':utf8' if $DB::OUT;
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the "Wide characters" error at the debugger. But now I have further problems with the program - it doesn't seem to handle the Unicode characters correctly - I wonder If I should continue on this question, or open a new one

Comment: Open a new one. This isn't a forum discussion, it's a Q&A site. Combining multiple questions into a single one will just confuse people who later come looking for these same answers.

Comment: OK, I will mark this answer as the solution, and open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is in some part of the code that you haven't shown us.  I base this suspicion on the following facts:

1. The error message you quote says `at (eval 155)`.  There are no `eval`s in your code.
2. The code you *have* shown us above does *not* produce a "wide character" warning when I run it, even if the input contains Unicode characters.  The only way I can make it produce one is to comment out *both* the `use open` line and the `binmode STDOUT` line.

Admittedly, my testing environment is not exactly identical to yours: I'm on Linux, and my Perl is only v5.10.1, meaning that I had to lower the version requirement and turn off the [`unicode_strings` feature](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/lib/feature.pm#the_%27unicode_strings%27_feature) (not that you're actually using it).  Still, I very much suspect that the problem is not in the code you've posted.

Comment: Apparently the eval is with the debugger (I've been running it under Padre). When I run the program without the debugger, It says:

`Name "main::INPUT" used only once: possible typo at Conv.pl line 58.

Name "main::CONVTABLE" used only once: possible typo at Conv.pl line 26.

Name "main::OUTPUT" used only once: possible typo at Conv.pl line 71.

Conversion table: opening file: E:\My Documents\Perl\Conversion table.txt

∩╗┐England, Germany

he, she

the, HOMHOM

<╫ö╫ó╫¿╫│11> <╫ö╫ó╫£╫Ö╫ò╫ƒ>

<╫ù ╫Ö╫│ ╫¥> <╫ù╫Ö╫Ö╫¥>`